# Python : How to parse the json data and render it use webapp2 on GAE and deployed the search-result app?

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine

everyone : )
I have A database that can search like "http://key.xxxxxx.org:10093/?q="
when type the keyword in url (behind the =mark), it can show lots of json data.

Now i write a simple webapp on GAE use webapp2 : on the /search page, when i type the keyword,
it can parse the jsondata content on the /result page. Here is my part of code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import re
import httplib
import json
import urllib
from string import letters

import webapp2
import jinja2

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                               autoescape = True)

def render_str(template, **params):
    t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
    return t.render(params)

def renderJson(query):
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('xxx.xxxxx.org:10093')
    conn.request('GET', '/?q=%s' % urllib.quote_plus(query))
    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()
    j = json.loads(data)
    results = []
    result = j['data']['group'][0]['resultitem']
    for l in result:
        for k,v in l.items():
            if k == 'word':
                results.append(l[k])
    return results

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(render_str(template, **kw))

    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

class Search(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("search.html")

    def post(self):
        q = self.request.get('query')
        if q:
            self.redirect('/result/?q='+query)


class Result(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        q = self.request.get('query')
        self.render('result.html', query = q, result = renderJson(q))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                               ('/search', Search),
                               ('/result', Result)
                               ],
                              debug=True)
```

## in the search.html, i wrote

```
<input type="text" name="q" value="{{query}}"></input>
```

and in result.html

```
<p>{{result}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the parameter from the url you need to use:

```
q = self.request.get('query')
```

See the [Getting Started guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/handlingforms) and the [webapp improved documentation](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html).

Then you would pass that parameter to `renderJson` as `renderJson(q)`, also in `renderJson`
the second line will need to quote the query string first (and pass the q argument)

```
conn.request('GET', '/?q=%s' % urllib.quote(query))
```

Finally for rendering the final output please read the [Getting Started Guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates).

Comment: Thank you very much : )  I saw the document that you suggest, i confused that the renderJson() and the q are not in A class, can't share the same method, so how can i fix it ? "q=self.request" may in the get() or post() in class ,not in renderJson() ?

Comment: So you need to change your renderJson method to accept a parameter. def renderJosn(query), and then as explained in the answer used that parmeter to build the url.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Here is a last question about parse json: if i have a json data like this : {"total":1,"data":[{"outGuaranteeTime":"","assetsNum":"B50070100007003","cabinet":"H05","deviceModel":"PowerEdge 1950","buyTime":"2009-06-29","idc":"杭州德胜机房"}]}
>>> type(data)  how can i print every value in the json use for_loop ? like  print ddata['data'][0]['idc'] , but this is only one value, no loop, can you show me ? i just about newer

Comment: If you just want to print all data just do print ddata. You can also use the pprint module(http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html), to print it with a  nicer format.

Comment: Thank you very very much...but i still confused about the 'params passing issue', i really need a exampleCode to learn it.. So, i edit the original questioncode above, can you edit it, change it to example code? please help me... Thankssss, Finally, need type keyword in search.html and blahblahblah output in result.html

Comment: I don't understand the problem you are facing now, can you elaborate? There is a full explained application in the Getting Started Guide.
However, I do see some problems, search.html is a template which is expecting a parameter query, but no parameter is passed when rendering it. The result.html template is trying to print a list, instead you need to iterate and print each element. Also the lines for k,v in l.items(): if k == 'word': results.append(l[k]) could be replaced by results.append(l['word']).

Comment: :I changed the code in question area, feel confused about how pass the params in class search and class result, and search redirect to result, i wrote some code in there, can you fix it? Thank you  : (

Comment: i think a while according your search.html advice, the search class's def get, just render the html, there is no need parameter ? post need ?